# What is the source for the custom of kissing one's hand after shaking another's?

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, provenance, hands-fingers, kissing

There is a common custom in Israel (mostly in Sfardic communities) that after you shake someone's hand, you kiss your hand. Generally people kiss their thumb or first two fingers, in my experience. (For another question mentioning this custom, see [Kissing the hand to catch a cold?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23551/kissing-the-hand-to-catch-a-cold).)

What is the source/origin of this custom?
Was it started by some rabbi? If so, who? And when?
Also, is it attested to in any writings? (i.e. reasons for doing it)

Comment: The Ben Ish Chai brings such an idea in Od Yosef Chai

Comment: @Scimonster: I do not have a source, but as to the reason: A Sefardi person I asked explained the following: A person shake hands with the right hand, and uses the left hand in the washroom.  Kissing the right hand after shaking hands is affirming you believe the person whose hand you just shook is aware and observant of the above difference; i.e. you kiss your hand to show that you trust their right hand is "tahor".