# How To Prevent Eyes from wondering

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, chabad, chasidut-hasidism, satmar, breslov

My name is Ariel and I am converting to Judaism. I am converting with Chabad (I am aware Chabad does not have any beys dins), and Bezrat Hashem I will be wearing a Black Fedora very soon. However, I have a problem. I go to a secular school (at least for another week) where the women  are not modest and they have this cheerleading nonesense all Sheker. I am Shomer Habrit for the most part, I do not spill seed Baruch Hashem. However, my eyes sometimes wonder and I feel extremely bad about it. What do I do?

Comment: Actually, perhaps http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48831/759 is a better dupe?