# Is shaking hands with opposite sex permitted at a business meeting?

Tags: halacha, negia

I am sure many people face this awkwardness and confusion when facing a hand shake moment  by the opposite gender. Of course I am referring to business meetings.  I would like to know what the Halakha says and when can one be lenient.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Eli, and welcome to Mi Yodea. This is a great question for the site (with the usual disclaimer that for practical rulings you need to consult your own Rabbi), but it has already been asked, so it has been closed as a duplicate. But don't let that discourage you, and please stay around and feel free to ask and answer more questions. You also may be interested in [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7531/how-to-tactfully-circumvent-opposite-gender-handshake) in particular.